# Why can't I put the comparator inside the node?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am using priority_queue to solve a problem.
I intend to declare my node in the following way.

```
struct node{
         int x, y, val;
         node(int _x, int _y, int _val){
             x = _x;
             y = _y;
             val = _val;
         }
         bool operator < (const node& rhs) const{
             return val > rhs.val;
         }
     };
```

and use it in the following way:

```
priority_queue<node, vector<node>, node> queue;
```

But it doesn't work.

Then, I switch to another way. It works.

```
struct node{
         int x, y, val;
         node(int _x, int _y, int _val){
             x = _x;
             y = _y;
             val = _val;
         }

     };
struct com{
    bool operator () (const node& lhs, const node& rhs) const{
             return lhs.val > rhs.val;
         }
};
priority_queue<node, vector<node>, com> queue;
```

I don't know why there is a difference. Any advice would be great.

Given the following answer, I have tried different ways to run my code, they works:

Version 1

```
struct node{
         int x, y, val;
         node(int _x, int _y, int _val){
             x = _x;
             y = _y;
             val = _val;
         }
         node(){}

        bool operator () (const node& lhs, const node& rhs) const{
         return lhs.val > rhs.val;
     }
 };

priority_queue<node, vector<node>, node> queue;
```

Version 2:

```
struct node{
         int x, y, val;
         node(int _x, int _y, int _val){
             x = _x;
             y = _y;
             val = _val;
         }
    bool operator < (const node& rhs) const{
         return val > rhs.val;
     }

 };
priority_queue<node, vector<node>, less<node>> queue;
//or
//priority_queue<node, vector<node>> queue;
//or
//priority_queue<node> queue;
```

Comment: Because in your node, it isn't `operator()` that is defined. You can just use `std::less<node>` to make it work, or just omit the comprator.

Comment: Don't you notice any difference between the comparison operator in the `node` structure and the function call operator in the `com` structure? Like one being a ***comparison operator*** and the other a ***function call*** operator?

Comment: Not that you need the extra template argument in the first example, because then the default  `std::less` will be used that uses the `<` operator. So in the first example all you need is `priority_queue<node> queue;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node` isn't default constructible and it doesn't have `operator()`

Since you're using `operator<`, you don't need to specify the comparator, because the default is `std::less<T>`, which uses it if its available. And if you don't need to specify comparator, there's no reason to specify container, as `std::vector<T>` is already the default.

```
priority_queue<node, vector<node>, less<node>> queue; 
// same as
priority_queue<node, vector<node>> queue;
// also same as
priority_queue<node> queue;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case,`node` is a **not** comparator as such — instead, it provides an overload for `operator<` , so you should use this:

```
priority_queue<node, vector<node>> queue;
```

without any third argument. That should work.

Note that a *comparator* is one which can be invoked as:

```
cmp(x,y)
```

So in that sense, your class `node` doesn't support that — it, however, supports this:

```
x < y
```

which is a different thing, and as such, can be used with the default comparator `std::less<T>`, used by `std::priority_queue`.

Answer (score 0):

The `priority_queue` literally calls `com(arg1, arg2)` during its evaluation.

That function needs to be available either as a function-object (as it is in your example that works), a static function, or a lambda. Your first `struct` has none of these.

Answer (score 0):

Because the 3rd template argument accept only the compareFunction( objA, objB ) format. By default, it is `class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>`, which the std::less calls the operator<().

The following code should works

```
std::priority_queue<node, std::vector<node>> queue;
```